# Fraction of the linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, fractions

Let $C=[0,1)\times [0,1)$. For any $v\in R^2$, we have $v=[v]+\{v\}$, where $[v]\in Z^2,\{v\}\in C$. $L$ is an euclidean segment of $C$ if it is the intersection of $C$ and a segment in an affine line of $R^2$.

For $A\in M_2(Z)$ being a integer matrix, let $T_A:C\rightarrow C,v\rightarrow\{Av\}$. And $v\in C$ is $T_A$-periodic if exists $n>0$ such that $T_A^nv=v$.

(1)Prove that if $\det(A)=0$, then $\operatorname{im}(A)$ is a finite union of euclidean segment of $C$.

(2)Proof that if $\det(A)\neq 0$, then the set of $T_A$-periodic points is dense in $C$.

Comment: I'm afraid of the questions about fractional and interger parts. Where can I find some books to study them? Thanks very much.

Comment: For $A\in M_2(Z)$, I have considered its Smith form. For $det(A)=0$, A can be diag(d,0) with respect to a particular basis, but I don't know how to do next.